# Thymeleaf iterating a Java 8 Stream from Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-el

My Google-Fu is failing me so I ask you... Is there a way to iterate a Java 8 Stream with Thymeleaf similar the way one iterates a List while still keeping Stream's performance purpose?

Repository

```
Stream<User> findAll()
```

Model

```
Stream<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("users", users);
```

View

```
<div th:each="u: ${users}">
   <div th:text="${u.name}">
```

If I try this, I get:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head' - maybe not public?
```

If I use a List instead, it works as expected.

Is there a proper way to handle a Stream that I'm failing to find?

Comment: Not that I can see either.  You can, as you mentioned, convert to a List: `List<User> result = users.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and looking on the Thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration) there is no way to do what you want.

Besides Thymeleaf doesn't provide any way to interact with streams, take into account that `Stream` objects hasn't access to its contained objects till you do a terminal operation (for example `Collectors.toList()`)

Answer (score 3):

While Thymeleaf doesn't support streams as per the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values) it does support Iterable, so you can do the following:

Model:

```
Stream<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("users", (Iterable<User>) users::iterator);
```

And your view will work as you have already written it:

```
<div th:each="u: ${users}">
    <div th:text="${u.name}">
```

Looking at the version 3 [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values) it says that it will support any object which implements Iterator so it should also be possible to do this:

Model:

```
Stream<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
model.addAttribute("users", users.iterator());
```

I'm not using that version, so I haven't been able to get that to work though.

Answer (score 1):

This post a bit old, but I didn't see any newer one. It can be done with the right secret sauce.

In the Java code, you have to do three things:

1. Use the @javax.transaction.Transactional annotation
2. Manually call Thymeleaf to process the template
3. Use a try-with-resources block on template processing to guarantee the stream is closed

In your template, you don't have to do anything different if you pass the Stream's iterator, as Thyemeleaf already understand iterators.

The @Transactional annotation is required when returning streams from Spring Data. The key is that the annotated method has to actually consume the stream before it ends - this won't happen using Thyemleaf the "normal" way where the method just returns the String template name.

At the same time, the stream has be closed (something you don't have to do when using streams to do stuff like convert a List to a Map). By controlling the template generation process yourself, you can ensure that the stream is closed and consumed within your @Transactional method.

The Java code looks like this (I'm using Spring 5 MVC):

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/customers")
    @Transactional
    public void customers(
        final String firstName,
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException {
        final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(
            request,
            response,
            request.getServletContext(),
            request.getLocale()
        );

        try (
            final Stream<CustomerModelEntity> models = 
                (firstName == null) || firstName.isEmpty() ?
                customerRepository.findAll() :
                customerRepository.findByFirstNameIgnoringCaseOrderByLastNameAscFirstNameAsc(firstName)
        ) {
            ctx.setVariable(
                "customers",
                models.iterator()
            );

            response.setContentType("text/html");

            templateEngine.process(
                "customer-search",
                ctx,
                response.getWriter()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The Thymeleaf template looks as follows (I'm using decoupled logic):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<thlogic>
  <attr sel=".results" th:remove="all-but-first">
    <attr sel="/.row[0]" th:each="customer : ${customers}">
      <attr sel=".first-name" th:text="${customer.firstName}" />
      <attr sel=".middle-name" th:text="${customer.middleName}" />
      <attr sel=".last-name" th:text="${customer.lastName}" />
    </attr>
  </attr>
</thlogic>
```